# image upload with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Am having difficulties uploading images with codeigniter it keeps saying that i didn't select a file to upload.

this is my code

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '3000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }else{
        echo $this->upload->data();
    }
}
```

it doesn't even send the image to the directory.

Comment: maybe some output would be helpful?

Comment: i dont get, pls explain. am not pro!

Comment: @DanielBarde: Please include any specific error message or output you are receiving. Additionally, you may want to include your view code as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this function instead :

```
function upload_done() {
 $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
 $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
 $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
 $config['upload_path'] = '/var/www/uploadfiles/'; // use an absolute path
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
 $config['max_size'] = '0'; 
 if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
 $this->load->library('upload',$config);
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload() )
 {
  echo "UPLOAD ERROR ! ".$this->upload->display_errors();
 } else {
  echo "THE IMAGE HAS BEEN UPLOADED : "; var_dump( $this->upload->data() );
 }
}
```

Comment: but i want to run a query at once and store the full path to the image on my images table how do i get the full path. this is the array that contains all the image info. $this->upload->data()

Comment: You'll find what you need in 

**$t=$this->upload->data(); $full_path_to_image=$t['full_path'];**

to store all the array, just do :

**`$this->db->insert('images_table', $t);`**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your html looks like below.

```
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
```

Codeigniter's upload library assumes the name to be "userfile"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the call to do_upload() depending on the name you have given the form input. Lets say you have this code in your HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="image" />
```

You need to change:

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

to

```
$this->upload->do_upload('image')
```

By default CodeIgniter assumes the name is "userfile".